# Creating custom shaped Timeline in Java SE

Tags: java, graphics

I'm going to create a custom shaped Timeline graph (to show and save as an image) in J2SE;
is the any framework for this? or I should start from Graphics2D?
Where should I start?

Thanks

Comment: An image would be nice. Have you tried looking at [JFreeCharts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I need custom shapes and custom format; can `JFreeCharts` do that?

Comment: Take a look at see. Otherwise you'll probably end up having to code it yourself

Comment: @MadProgrammer: No, it doesn't; Now where is the start point to do it by myself? Graphics2D on a JPanel? or these kind of things are done in a different way?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start